# Can we check Current Default browser in iOS programatically?

Tags: ios, browser, default-browser

I am developing a browser-based application and had applied for default browser entitlements. I have received the provisioning entitlements from Apple and I am able to successfully set my app as the Default Browser. However, i am unable to determine programmatically if my App is currently set as Default Browser by the user or not.
Is there any way I can determine the current Default Browser set by the user in iOS programmatically? My App supports iOS 14 and above.